# Getting an error when trying to execute a project referencing a dll library project through Web.config

Tags: c#, web-config, preconditions

My solution's Web app has a Web.config file referencing a project's module that needs to be called as a `precondition`:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="MyTestProject.ErrorModule.ErrorHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
          <add verb="TRACE" allowed="false"/>
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

When I'm running my project, I'm getting an error right away saying the following:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load type `'MyTestProject.ErrorModule.ErrorHandler'`.
```

I cannot run that Test project by itself, since it doesn't have `Main` method since it's a library.

The starting project used to be set to run on `Framework 2.0`, but I needed to change it to `Framework 4.0` since it needs to reference `System.Web.Extensions.dll`

The target `Framework` for `MyTestProject` is `4.6.1`

What am I missing here?